# What is the keyword used to write a synopsis in LaTeX?

Tags: document-classes, keywords

I am writing the synopsis of my project. I don't know whether synopsis keyword exist or not:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{synopsis}
```

Comment: Welcome! What you are looking for is a "document class", and no, I'm afraid there isn't one specific for your current need. However you don't necessarily need to use a `synopsis` class to write a synopsis. You can use some other basic class, like `article`.

Comment: `\section*{Synopsis}` ?